# WCF subscriber specific update?

Tags: .net, wcf, publish-subscribe

Does anyone know of any good step by step examples ... or examples period, of a WCF Pub Sub service that allows multiple connections, with username and password authentication, AND subscriber updates that are specific to the subscribed user name and password? (meaning, each user won't get every update, but just ones specific to their user) ... I did find [this example](http://www.anujvarma.com/series/wcf-publish-subscribe-c/) which was great, but something more specific to the situation above would be awesome.... Thank you.

Comment: Does anyone have good suggestions for WCF books the cover config files, and topic based models? I've found several online, but it's hard to tell what they entail from the description... I may have to just go to Barnes and Noble, and check 'em all out.

Answer (score 0):

Are you very specific about WCF?

If not, then you can look at JMS technologies like ActiveMQ, which help you in publishing based on TOPIC or Queue and will deliver only to the topic subscribers. But there is no username password authentication there. You might need to use NMS for connecting from C#.

If you are looking for a browser level Live update/ Server push then COMET is what you are looking for.

Comment: Your suggestion is great! and I will use that in other projects, but I  do need WCF with username password authentication for this specific project..

Comment: You can probably use comet with a layer of authentication. Try looking at flycomet project in codeplex site. Disclaimer: That is my small project  about Comet. Sorry for self publicity :)